# Remote logging - Nginx over Rsyslog or any other alternative

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2, logging, rsyslog

I need to setup centralized remote access logging of Auto Scaling Instances. Currently I have Rsyslog / Apache2 logging working just fine, but for the new project Nginx is used and I don't see any possibility to log directly over TCP/UDP. Rsyslog can be configured to send data remotely reading local file, but my goal is to avoid local writes at all.

Can someone share the knowledge on how to configure Nginx to send messages over Network instead of local FS? Or maybe I might need to configure log rotation to scp files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a FIFO (pipe), tell nginx to log to that, and have your syslog daemon read the FIFO and send those messages to a remote location.  Both rsyslog and syslog-ng can do this.

Comment: In this case, why not just let Nginx to log to default file and then use Rsyslog to read and send it remotely? What is the benefit of FIFO?

Comment: Because you said you wanted to avoid local writes.  A FIFO doesn't write to disk, it's just a small chunk of memory that buffers writes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [nginx_udplog_module](https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-udplog-module).  It looks like it hasn't been updated in a while, but it may still work.